Odoo: install external dependencies
How do I install external dependencies on odoo.sh 17?
For example, I need the Microsoft ODBC driver for this app.
However, when I follow the installation instructions from here, and try to install the driver using the odoo shell, I get a permissions error:
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
Insufficient permissions to install Homebrew to "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew" (the default prefix).
I know how to add Python libraries using requirements.txt, see here, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do the same for non-Python dependencies.
